# After Effects Camera Solve crashing?

Tags: after-effects, tracker

I am using the camera tracker on a clip of roughly 10000 frames 740x360, 50fps, prores codec. There are a lot of trackable features in the clip.

When I use the tracker on only a part of the video the tracking completes in less than a minute. But when I try to camera solve the whole clip solving is not done even after 10 hours (I let it run over night).

I was thinking that maybe there is a hard to solve part of the video, so I cut the clip up into multiple parts and solved each of them separately, they all got solved just fine in a few minutes, so I don't think that is the case.

Do any of you know of similar occurrences or of a way to solve that problem?

Answer (score 1):

Something that helps a lot is using super high shadow/highlight and contrast in a pre-comp so that ae has more clarity between different parts of the shot and therefore tracks better.

1. Pre-compose your shot (right click and select pre-compose)
2. Apply Shadow/Highlights using Shadow/Highlights and/or lumetri color
3. Apply contrast once, twice, or more if needed to get strong edges for ae to see everything and track the shot.

   - Note: You can remove these effects later, this is just to help ae "see" better to track the shot.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm not sure if I understand but the tracker is not supposed to be over the whole image. You need to chose one specific part that is in a contrast to the surroundings and chose that as the tracking point.

Comment: I'm actually talking about the camera solver, sorry for the confusion